# How can I get access to python 3.4 after installing Anaconda?

Tags: 16.04, python, anaconda

I recently started working with Ubuntu and got stuck with a problem. I downloaded Anaconda version 3.4 for Linux and installed it using the command : 
`bash ./Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`

when I run the command `python --version` or `python3 --version` I get this result:

```
Python 2.7.12+
Python 3.5.2+
```

which has to be `Python 2.7.12 :: Continum Analytics inc.`

It is probably because Ubuntu has python 2.7 and python 3.4 installed by default.

What can I do to get access to python with anaconda libraries?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `anaconda path` to your `.bashrc` file like this:

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/home/george/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

Why your installer didn't add it is another issue, but `source` your `.bashrc` file just to be sure, or better still look in there if not there then add the *line above* and `source` it to make it take effect.

Comment: Was it there already or you had to enter it manually?

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please accept the answer! Also, consider using virtual environments, you can use anaconda to manage multiple conda envs, `virtualenv` (by itself or in combo with `virtualenvwrapper`) or `venv` (this one comes with Python from 3.4 onward).